# How to count the number of blank cells in one column based on the first blank row in another column

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet set up with tv program titles in column B, the next 20 or so columns are tracking different information about that title.  I need to count the number of blank cells in column R relating to the range in column B that contains titles (ie, up to the first blank row in column B.)

I can easily set up a formula to count the number of empty cells in a given range in column R, the problem is as I add more titles to the sheet I would have to keep updating the range in the formula [a simple `=COUNTIF(R3:R1108, "")`].  I've done a little googling of the problem but haven't quite found anything that fits the situation.  I thought I would be able to get the following to work but I didn't fully understand what was going on with them and they weren't giving the expected results.

I've tried these formulas:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(MIN("B3:B"&MIN(IF((R3:R)>"",ROW(B3:B)-1)))))
```

---

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(INDIRECT("B3:B"&MIN(IF((R3:R)>"",ROW(B3:B)-1)))))
```

And

```
=if(SUM(B3:B)="","",SUM(R3:R))
```

All of the above formulas give "0" as the result.  Based on the `COUNTIF` formula I have set up it should be 840, which is a number I would expect.  Currently, there are 1106 rows containing data and 840 is a reasonable number to expect in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

`=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("R",3,":R",(3+COUNTA(B3:B)))))`

This counts the number of non-blank rows in the B column (starting at B3), and uses that to determine the rows to perform `COUNTBLANK` in, in column R (starting at R3). `CONCATENATE` is a way to give it a range by adding strings together, and the `INDIRECT` allows for the range reference to be a string.

Comment: Thanks!  It appears to work close enough for goverment work.  The COUNTIF statement gives me a number that's 1 smaller than the formula you just gave me but I'm not going to quibble about that and call it good.

Answer (score 0):

a proper way would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3, 18, 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(MAX(IF(B3:B<>"", ROW(B3:B), )), 18, 4)))
```

[image: 0]

---

or shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("R3:"&
 ADDRESS(MAX(IF(B3:B<>"", ROW(B3:B), )), 18, 4))))
```

---

or shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("R3:R"&MAX(IF(B3:B<>"", ROW(B3:B), ))))
```